# How fetch and wait 5 seconds and get source code of page

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have two websites, the first get web source code of the second (The two websites aren't one same host -> CORS). (The second website is not mine)

Example:

```
fetch("https://api.allorigins.win/get?url=" + url)
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        }
        
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
    })
    .then(data => {
        var html = stringToHTML(data.contents);
    });
```

It works, except that the concern is that the second page displays other elements several seconds after being displayed, so it does not display me because I retrieved the page too early.

How to make it wait a few seconds before recovering, while not forgetting that "api.allorigins.win"?

Do you have an idea? ( I use Vanillia JS )

Comment: Use a setTimeout(() => { do what you need 5 seconds after}, 5000); plus you could use async/await and not .then woulf be easier to wait for the time you need

Comment: Only adding a timeout will not help -- that will not magically change the HTML. The Asker is really asking for any dynamic code -- that is embedded in the response -- is *executed*. What you need here is a browser instance, e.g. a [headless browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser). Tools like Selenium could be of use. Or write your own plug-in for some web browser, or use a generic one like GreaseMonkey and the likes.

Comment: Like @trincot said. Or, if it's not too complicated, you can inspect that other page and reproduce its behavior on your side (for example check if it calls another API).

Comment: I tried to see by inspecting the page, looking at the requests etc, but it displays a unique trick, which is to my knowledge impossible to retrieve. And since I'm in vanillia js, do you have an example of a headless browser?

Answer (score 0):

Allorigins that must wait for rendering, but it does not.

Your alternative is to implement your own version of allorigins using an headless browser that waits the page render before returning it html. There's no ready solution for it

Comment: For that I must start a server ? Or that can be managed by the client ?

Comment: It must be on a server

Comment: Is there no alternative to Allorigins that can do this? (so I don't need to put a server online). Otherwise what can I modify in their code?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you're using a framework or any library to handle the DOM, but with vanilla JS you can do something like this to check if your DOM element is ready

```
const DOMReadyCheck = setInterval(() => {
if (document.getElementsBy...) { //get your element here
//send your fetch request and set your element with data
clearInterval(DOMReadyCheck);
}
```

Comment: What DOM element? It’s HTML source code, not a DOM.